# Using Bigcommerce how do I hide certain nav items in the header but keep them in the footer?

Tags: html, css, header, footer, bigcommerce

I used this code below which worked. But how do I also hide other childs from the header but not in the footer?

```
  .header  .navPages ul li:last-child { display:none; }

</style>
```

Comment: What do you mean by hide other childs? Do you mean that you want to hide all of your product subcategories in the header navigation?

Comment: thank you, theres a switch on the backend the shows all web pages so the header would look like "home" "blog" "Returns" "Store" "Etc"     that code above helped me remove the last navigation item but how do I hide multiple?

Comment: Here's some info on how to use nth child selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: anyone else have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is going to be a little different depending on whether you want to select multiple nav items individually, select a range, etc.

Here's an example of CSS that would select hide all nav items after the first 5:

```
.header  .navPages ul li:nth-child(n+6) { 
   display:none; 
}
```

Here's an example of hiding a specific nav item (the fifth one):

```
.header  .navPages ul li:nth-child(5) { 
    display:none; 
}
```

You can use multiple rules targeting individual nav items, or you use nth child selectors to target by odd/even, every fourth item, etc.

If you want to see more examples, this page might help: https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Comment: You are my hero <3

Comment: Ended up using this code 
<style>
.header  .navPages ul li:nth-child(n+7) { 
   display:none; 
}

.header  .navPages ul li:nth-child(3) { 
    display:none; 
}

</style>

Comment: Awesome, glad that helped point you in the right direction :)